# Is an 'exterior' California corner acceptable?

Tags: framing

[image]

I know the top California corner is acceptable (and preferred for insulation advantages), but is the bottom corner a sound technique?

Comment: Are you asking about the exterior of the building or just "outside" corners on interior walls?

Answer (score 3):

These two are effectively the same corner.  One is just rotated 180 degree from the other.  you can clearly see that in this edited image:

[image: Modified image]

The only thing that's different is that you are showing only the interior wall finish.

So yes, this is perfectly acceptable and commonly done.